# Converting .NetCore- Cshtml project to React UI

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net

we got an a .NetCore project.UI and MW are seperately diffrent project.

UI project is an normal .net project, cshtml with jquery .net controllers,entities(multi layer).
We want make our UI to React (page by page if its possible)

I started searching but there are a lot of frameworks around, AntDesing, MaterialUI, MaterilaKit ...

Our APP contains mostly datatable and Modals

So Can someone show me the path of convert. Thank you

EDIT

React is a spa ,in our current sitiation when user clicks any button all the page is navigating,refreshing etc. it looks old and not good for UX,

Mobile responsibility is a plus but we already have mobile apps.

We are wanting to make our app more easy to use, looking good and faster

Comment: Do you need server side rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I do not give you the answer you want since your question is quite cryptic.

For any transition from one to another technology it is wise to first prepare a list of requirements and to make clear what you actually want to achieve. You would see that many frameworks are not needed if you do a quick exam of your requirement list. Also your questions on stackoverflow will become much more specific and therefore better to answer by the community.

It is quite a difference if you just want to do a 1 to 1 transition since you want to use recent technologies or if you are anticipating for a new world of possibilities (like Server-Side rendering, mobile support, ... you name it)

**Question to concider**

- Why do you want to do a transition? Do you want to have a 1 to 1 transition to a new framework? Does that match with your future goals? (Maintainability, sustainability, extendability, ...)
- Eg. Should you support mobile layouts => Every framework (React, VueJs, Angular, ....) has its own vision how and to what extend mobile is supported.
- Which framework do you prefer and why does those meet your criteria
- Which framework fall off the list and why did thos not meet your criteria
- ..

**Strategy**

Also here there is a big world to explore. Is your current application already in Production and should it be fully supported while you make the transition. Is it possible to "move" functionality to a new application and do a transition where the customer is involved by any step you make?